# Print all the values of the List except the last one.

Tags: java, list

I have this code:

```
List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list1.add(100);
    list1.add(200);
    list1.add(300);
    list1.add(400);
    list1.add(500);
    list1.add(600);

Integer LastElement = list1.get(list1.size()-1);

System.out.println("Values of the list:" + list1-LastElement); !!!
```

The values of the list should be: 100, 200, 300, 400, 500. 
And `list1-LastElement` gives me an error! Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Anytime you get an error, post the error in your question

Comment: If you want to discard the last element, then print until the `list1.size() - 2` th

Comment: @higuaro list1.size()-2 gives me only the index of the forth value in the list starting from 0

Comment: @Nora he meant use list1.size() -2 for the number of iteration in your for loop .. if you want to get elements from an ArrayList use list.get(x) as mentioned by the answers below

Answer (score 5):

What you are trying to do is subtract the value 600 (the last value of the arraylist) from the length of the arraylist. This makes no sense. Instead try the following (if you are trying to print everything but the last element):

```
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size() - 1; i++) {
     System.out.println(list1.get(i));
}
```

What this will do will print everything but the last element. Hence the

```
list1.size() - 1
```

Comment: @MLavernetyev thank you, and in list1.get() you need an i. So you have list1.get(i)

Answer (score 1):

to print values in a list you need to loop over it:

```
for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {
    System.out.println(list1.get(i))
}
```

to print values in a list without the last one you need to shorten the loop:

```
for(int i=0;i<list1.size()-1;i++) {
    System.out.println(list1.get(i))
}
```

Comment: but list1 is not an Array, it is an ArrayList so I got an error ! list1[i] does not work!

Answer (score 0):

To get a sublist of a `List`, use `subList`. (The key there is to already know the name of the method. The API docs are easy enough to browse.)

```
if (list1.size() >= 1) {
    System.out.println(
        "Values of the list:" +
        list1.subList(0, list1.size()-1)
    );
}
```

Note that the `List` returned by `subList` is a live view. Setting elements of one or other list updates the other. Further information in the API docs.